# Google Street View streets not rendering correctly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-maps, linux

I noticed that whenever I try to view some places through Google Street View using Ubuntu, streets are not displayed correctly: in particular, pretty much everything is blurred, i.e. not rendered correctly. This happens on every browser. No problems on Windows 10 instead. Did anyone have the same issue?